# jQuery .is(':hover') and $('div:hover').length don't work under FF and IE

Tags: jquery, html, hover, detect

No matter what I do, I can't get either
`.is(':hover')` or `$('div:hover').length` to work in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

`$('div:hover').length` always seems to be 0 on them, however in Chrome everything is detected and works as intended.

Please help

Comment: `$('div').is(':hover');` must work, if it doesn't something else is deflecting! not that it will return `true` or `false`

Comment: If you add a CSS rule for `div:hover`, does that work? Could be some other element obstructing the div.